Why does my computer not restart as expected?
I have an older Lenovo ThinkCentre desktop.
It works fine, but has a funny issue where it will not reboot.
I always have to shut it down completely with “Start -> Shutdown.”
If I click “Start -> Restart,” the screen will go dark like it's rebooting but it will just hang and never reboot.
I replaced the power supply and RAM but it didn't fix it.
Any ideas of what this could be or how to fix it?

Are you 100% sure its not rebooting? It could be rebooting but just not giving you any output until you are all the way into windows. I've seen that it outputs to a different connector during the BIOS boot sequence, and then in windows, switch over to another. For example SUB-D during Bios, hdmi during windows. Keep in mind that the reboot process takes a lot longer than hybrid shutdown, because then also the drivers get loaded. I'd restart and wait at least 10 minutes to be absolutely sure its not just this.

I'm pretty sure it is not rebooting. I waited 10 minutes and also cannot toggle the numlock light. The power light is on, fan spinning, but no POST.  I'll hold the power button until the light goes out, then push it again and the system will boot.

Ok, that is a good test, yes, then its indeed failing to reboot. You can look into the eventlog to see what is happening. It will log the restart in system, so you can see what the last event was.

I issued a reboot then checked the event log directly after.
There were no errors.
It showed the reboot event, services shutting down, then it showed it coming back online and services starting back up with zero warnings or errors.

Also want to add that I updated the BIOS to latest but that also didn't help me. I also did shutdown -r from CMD just to see if that was any different. It wasn't.

Only thing I can think of right now is that the PSU somehow isn't able to provide enough power during a split second, so I'd test with a different PSU to rule that out or confirm it. Other than that, no clue.

"different PSU"  ... this was my first thought and replacing the PS made no difference

Power reset your computer, hold the power button for 10 seconds to turn off
If it is a laptop with a removable battery, remove the battery for 30 seconds
then unplug your power adapter for 30 seconds, and power on your computer.

This is not a permanent solution, and OP already mentioned that they did this in the comments on the question. Therefor also a -1 from me.

this is a desktop
